# Manipulating Fields into Date Variable in R

Tags: r, date, variables

I have a dataset in R, PastActivity.csv, with a field named `month`.

```
Month
April-2017
May-2018
```

Unlike MS Excel, R does not read this as a date function but as a Factor.
Having failed on trying to change it using the `as.Date` function I tried the following.

```
PastActivityDate <- data.frame(Day = rep("01 -", nrow(PastActivity)), PastActivity)
```

Create a new data frame with additional column 'Date' with '01 - ' entries

```
PastActivityDate$Month <- cbind(PastActivityDate$Day, PastActivityDate$Month)
```

Combine the original field with the newer one

```
PastActivityDate$Month<- as.Date(PastActivityDate$Month)
```

Convert to date variable

The following error message shows:

> Error in as.Date.default(PastActivityDate$Month) :    do not know how
>   to convert 'PastActivityDate$Month' to class “Date”

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this assuming your data frame is named `df`:

```
PastActivity$newdate <- as.Date(paste("01-", PastActivity$month, sep = ""), format = "%d-%B-%Y")
```

This code will create a new column with a date object (first of the month)

Comment: Your inner paste query doesnt seem to be working right. It only returns the '01-' without the df$month concatenated

Comment: I have edited the df name to the one you have mentioned

Comment: Thanks. I managed that. What I meant that the paste function you used returns only '01-'. And when put through as.Date function returns a list of NAs

Comment: I am not sure why that is the case because it is running fine on my machine. Can you share a screenshot of the code you are running

Comment: Ive found what the cause was. R is a case sensitive lang. Something I was doing incorrectly. Thanks. Thumbs up Dude